# create Band Matrix in Java

Tags: java, matrix

I am new in Java and I have one question about band matrix in Java. I have Matrix A with size 8x8 and the band width is 3. I searched in the internet but I couldn't find any relevant example for band matrix in java. can any body give me a solution for creating a band matrix with java? THX for your help

Comment: You should make your hands dirty with

Comment: The intent is not clear to me. Do you want minimizing storage?

Comment: You should try something first and come back here if you get stuck.